# Is it possible to export everything inside an ASP Panel to .DOC, .XLS

Tags: c#, asp.net, export

Before getting into trouble, i would like to confirm few things with you. I am working in a dashboard project which contains, lots of controls. Everything will be inserted into a single panel control. The controls will be, table, grid, image, chart, some jquery plugins.

I would like to provide export option for word, excel, pdf. Is it possible in asp.net to export the single panel which has all the controls to word document.

Tell your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you have any dynamic client-side code then you can't do this.

There's no way of turning a portion of a document client-side into a .doc (closest you could do is a print-to-pdf which isn't as useful)

Normally you'd do something like this server side by generating the .doc with a library like aspose - but that's going to be a real pain to do yourself if you're presenting things involving jquery plugins.

To get the result you want you're likely going to have to bite on the bullet and recreate everything server-side to generate a .doc which the client can then download.

Comment: Every control is a separate user control. So both from client and server side code used to generate the control.

Comment: I'm talking about the actual final html when *rendered* using a HTML rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of make a screenshot of the screen using Javascript html2Canvas for example which builds the screen based on the information in the page, Im not sure but you may be able to send this information to the server, create a PDF then send it to the Browser (theoretically at least possible)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, pretty simple actually.  Here is an example exporting a Gridview to Excel.  You can do the same thing with any control.  Instead of this.gvRequests.RenderControl, substitute your Panel control.RenderControl.  Play around with it and see how it goes.

```
 //Export the datagrid to Excel
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SearchResults.xls");
        Response.ClearContent();


        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        this.gvRequests.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: dear steve, thanks for the useful information. But as i said in my description it is going to have controls like image chart and something else. If i render image control into StringWriter the output is going to be <img src='...' /> instead of the image. Thats why i am wondering.

Answer (score 0):

yes,

> static public void RenderToExcel(Panel panelReport1, Panel
>   panelReport2, Panel panelReport3, string strFileName)
>       {
>           HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear(); 
>           string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + strFileName + ".xls";
>           //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
>   attachment);
>           HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
>           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
>           HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
>           //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
>
> ```
>     //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
>     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
>     HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
>     panelReport1.RenderControl(htw);
>     if (panelReport2 != null)
>     {
>         panelReport2.RenderControl(htw);
>         if (panelReport3 != null)
>             panelReport3.RenderControl(htw);
>     }
>     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
>     Response.End();
>
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WebBrowser control server-side in code to request your own page in server memory and generate an image that way, or use this library (easier) http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/

EDIT

After pondering this for a bit what you want is already available!

User goes to web-page, presses ALT + Print Screen, Goes to Word or Excel whatever and presses  CTRL + P !!! job-done and it's all built in \0/ go home early :)